# Prove: $\forall x \gt 1, \arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = \arctan(x) - \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What I did is find the derivative of $\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$:

$$\frac{d\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

We can notice that that is the derivative of $arctan(x)$ as well.
So we can state the following:

$$\int\frac{d\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]}{dx}\cdot dx = \int\frac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}\cdot dx  $$

Now this is where I'm starting to have hesitations: We want to prove the equality $\forall x \gt 1 $, so what I think I should do is take those integrals from 1 to x. Indeed that works:

$$\int_1^x\frac{d\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]}{dx}\cdot dx = \int_1^x\frac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}\cdot dx   $$

If we simplify, we'll arrive to the desired equation. There are two problems with the above integral: at $x = 1, \arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ is not defined. However, $$\lim_{x\to1^+}\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Since we're not interested in x = 1, am I right in thinking that if the following equation is the correct formulation of the problem?

$$\lim_{h\to1^+}\left[\int_h^x\frac{d\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]}{dx}\cdot dx\right] = \lim_{h\to1^+}\left[\int_h^x\frac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}\cdot dx \right]$$

---

The other problem is that I don't think that the fact that two functions have equal area under their curve means they're necessarily equal to each other for all x. However if I prove that they are equal at a point $x_0$, and then prove that they are also equal at $x_0+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\to0^+$, then I prove that they are equal for all x greater than $x_0$

Is my reasoning corret?

**EDIT**: I noticed that I made a rather big copying mistake. Everywhere where I wrote

$$\int\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\cdot dx $$

I actually meant:

$$\int\frac{d\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]}{dx}\cdot dx $$

Which does indeed change the meaning of my equations by A LOT

Comment: It might be better to take $\tan$ of both sides.

Comment: When two functions have the same derivative, they differ by a constant. So you can't conclude that the function have the same antiderivative…

Comment: @Dirk the constant appears when you do the integral. In any case this concern goes away when we use definite intégrale.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. If you integrate the constant you'll get something. The functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=x+1$ have the same derivative but no definite or indefinite integral of them is the same.

Comment: The differ by a constant issue can be resolved by evaluating both sides of the equation at a single point.  If two functions differ by a constant, and they are equal at one point, they will be equal everywhere.

Comment: Actually, that is a very nice problem!

Comment: @Dirk how about approaching it from a purely trigonometric side? See my answer below. I'd be curious to know your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to use integrals. When two functions *defined over an interval* have the same derivative, they differ by a constant.

This is a consequence of the mean value theorem: if $f$ is a function having zero derivative over an interval, then, for $a,b$ in this interval,
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)=0
$$
so $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f$ is constant. So, if $f'(x)=g'(x)$ over an interval, the derivative of $F(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is zero and so $f(x)-g(x)$ is constant.

You have correctly proved that the two functions have the same derivative. Therefore there exists a constant $k$ such that
$$
\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}=k+\arctan x
$$
*for every* $x>1$.

Now we want to determine $k$. With the limit at $\infty$ is the easiest way:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\arctan(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(k+\arctan x)=k+\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
k+\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
and so
$$
k=-\frac{3\pi}{4}
$$

---

If you consider the same for $x<1$, you have
$$
\arctan\frac{x+1}{x-1}=k_1+\arctan x
$$
for a constant $k_1$ *possibly different from the above one*. Indeed, if we set $x=0$, we get
$$
\arctan1=k_1+\arctan0
$$
so
$$
k_1=\arctan1=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

---

(Edit: the question was edited to get rid of the error.)

<s>Your argument with integrals is faulty. The two functions have the same derivative, but this does not mean their integrals are equal.</s>

<s>What you can say is that, for an arbitrary $x_0>1$,</s>

Your argument with integrals can be made easier as follows: if $x_0>1$ is arbitrary,
$$
\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}-
\arctan\frac{1+x_0}{1-x_0}
=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt
=\arctan x-\arctan x_0
$$
by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Since this holds for every $x$ and every $x_0$, you can plug in a particular value of $x_0$ and get the required identity. Again, it's easier to do the limit for $x_0\to\infty$, so
$$
\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}+\frac{\pi}{4}=\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: I think, the book is right. You flipped the sign in one of the arctans.

Comment: 1- How this prove it for all x > 1? 2- It's 1-x, not x-1

Comment: @Dirk Thanks, I fixed the computation

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Yes, I fixed it. Since the identity $\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}=k+\arctan x$ holds for every $x>1$ because of the mean value theorem, you can compute this at an arbitrary $x$, but the easiest path here is using the limit at $\infty$. If $f(x)=g(x)$, then obviously the limit is the same!

Comment: I still don't see how it proves it for all x > 1. It proves they tend towards a same limit, differing by a constant.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for the double comment, we commented at the same time. The point is how do you come to prove that  $\arctan \frac{1+x}{1−x}=k+arctan x$ for all x > 1

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Since the derivative of $\arctan\frac{1+x}{1-x}-\arctan x$ is identically zero, this function is constant.

Comment: @egreg: Ok I get it. Except you need to take a = 1 in the MVT, and you run into what my question was actually about (the first part at least).

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Why should I? Just use any number greater than $1$.

Comment: Then you'll be proving that theorem for x > number

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite I added the argument with integrals.

Comment: @egreg  I think you misunderstood what I was trying to do. Setting the integrals equal to each other makes sense because their integrals are the same differing by a constant. What I set out to do is is find that constant, for all x > 1. I think the fact that the derivatives are equal in all x>1 means that that if I can find the constant in one point, then it is the same in every point.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite $x$ and $x+1$ differ by a constant, but $\int_h^x t\,dt\ne\int_h^x(t+1)\,dt$.

Comment: @egreg Integrating the derivative of x+1 gives x+c

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite So what? I can't understand what you're thinking to. The correct argument uses the FTC and I show how.

Comment: @egreg we're saying exactly the same thing in our equations, except I choose x0=1 and you x0=infinity

Comment: @egreg Greg, belated congratulations on your ascending to the 100K club.  Is it true that all is revealed to those attaining this status?  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I got over 500K on TeX.SX, but I'm still waiting for the revelation. ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Greg, you're quite welcome. I always enjoy reading your well-written solutions.  -Mark  P.S.  I'm disappointed that there was no "red carpet" celebration and no key to the club that Groucho couldn't get in.  ;-))

Comment: @egreg I re-read my question today and noticed a humongous mistake! The updated question is what it should have been originally :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say demonstrating this type of identities is easier and  more *essential* if you just work with trigonometric definitions, instead of basing your reasoning on concepts such as integrals and the Mean Value Theorem. After all, provided that angles are in the first quadrant, we are '*simply*' talking about ratios of right-angled triangles' sides. The rest can be deduced by symmetries.

Consider the following Figure.

[image]

$\triangle ABC$ is right-angled and such that $\overline{AC} = 1$ and $\overline{BC} = x>1$,
so that
\begin{equation} \alpha = \arctan x.\tag{1}\label{alpha}\end{equation}
Extend $AC$ to a segment $AD$, so that $\overline{CD} = x$. Let also $DH$ be the line perpendicular to $AB$.

Note that
$$ \angle ADB = \frac{\pi}{4},$$
and therefore
\begin{equation}\beta = \frac{3}{4}\pi -\alpha.\tag{2}\label{rel}\end{equation} 
Since
$$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ADH,$$
we obtain
$$\overline{DH} = x\overline{AH},$$
and, by Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle ADH$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{AH}^2 &=& \overline{AD}^2 - \overline{DH}^2=\\
 &=& (1+x)^2-\overline{AH}^2x^2,
\end{eqnarray} 
yielding
$$ \overline{AH} = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
and
$$\overline{DH} = \frac{x(x+1)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$
Finally
\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{BH} &=& \overline{AB}-\overline{AH}=\\
&=& \frac{x(x-1)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
We can conclude that
\begin{eqnarray}
\beta &=& \arctan\left(\frac{\overline{DH}}{\overline{BH}}\right)=\\
&=& \arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right).\tag{3}\label{beta}
\end{eqnarray}
Plugging \eqref{alpha} and \eqref{beta} into \eqref{rel}, and taking into account the odd symmetry of $\arctan(\cdot)$, leads to the desired result, i.e.
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = \arctan x - \frac{3}{4}\pi,$$
for $x>1$.
$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the function defined by

$f(x)=\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$.

for $|x|\neq1$.

We have
$f(\frac{1}{x})=-f(x)$ and
$f(-x)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}-f(x)$.

Assume now $x>1$ and put
$x=\tan(t)$ with $t\in(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Thus

$f(x)=\arctan(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+t))$
$=\frac{\pi}{4}+t-\pi$
$=\arctan(x)-\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

For the other cases $(x<-1,-1<x<0,0<x<1)$  we use the properties of the function $f$ we started with.

Comment: I can't parse this answer, sorry. To begin with: What is $f$?

Comment: @Dirk f is your function arctan((1+x)/(1-x)).